# Persian or Arabic Unicode UTF-8 character - how to print with Jzebra ? (print weird character)

Tags: java, javascript, zebra-printers, printers, thermal-printer

I'm using the [JZebra browser applet](http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/) to send raw commands to a thermal printer:

If I try to print Persian or Arabic characters like سلام that are encoded using UTF-8, I get some weird characters printed. I can't seem to grasp how to get the correct character.

I set the encoding to utf-8 like this:

```
document.jzebra.setEncoding("UTF-8");
```

But it still doesn't work.  How can I fix this?  Or is there any code like this could help me?

My Environment:

1. OS is win7 32bit
2. Using jZebra 1.4.5
3. my Printer is Jolimark TP280

Comment: Try using raw printing: http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/wiki/WhatIsRawPrinting  or postscript printing http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/wiki/WhatIsPostScriptPrinting

Comment: Please share the code that you use for printing as well.